# Why are Red_Black trees better than 2-3 trees?

Tags: performance, tree, binary-tree, red-black-tree, operation

Apart from red-blacks being easier to implement.

All operations (insertion, deletion, lookup) seem to have a time complexity of O(log n), in both trees. Is there a certain difference between these operations that I'm missing?

If you google search "red-black" "2-3 tree", you don't find any comparison between the two..

I've come to understand that red-blacks are generally considered to be the best. (I've heard that one of the reasons [EDIT] why red-blacks are faster than AVL trees (same category)[/EDIT] is efficiency in "application to persistent data structures", because of rebalancing efficiency; but that doesn't answer my question..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 2-3 trees, but I am pretty sure that B-Trees are by far the preferred for persistent database/filesystems.  Red/Black more often used in memory

Comment: Now when you say "used in memory" what does that mean exactly? (I've heard that before but I'm not sure what it refers to). Does it mean you literally load up the red-black program in your RAM? so then having a large data set wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Nevermind mate, it's definitely that; I've figured it out! That's why B-trees are used for persistent db and filesystems!

Comment: "used in memory" isnt that clear.  I meant generally shorter-term, non-persistent, RAM instead of hard-disk.  Example - t44444you open an interpreter, create such a tree (likely a dictionary that or something that is implemented by B-Tree) and start doing inserts and reads

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [Wikipedia entry for B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) (of which the 2 3 tree is a type of):

> Unlike self-balancing binary search
>   trees, the B-tree is optimized for
>   systems that read and write large
>   blocks of data. It is commonly used in
>   databases and filesystems.

Comment: Ok so 2-3 trees are actually faster at handling r&w on large blocks of data.